# Python for loop floating number subtraction

Tags: python, loops

The answer should be 49.8, 49.6, 49.4.... like this.what mistake I did?

```
import math
x = 50.0
for i in range(50):
    x = x - 0.20
    print(x)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsH7c.png)

Answer (score 0):

That ,,error'' is not an actual error. It comes from 1/3 == 0.333[3]. As a result, your 0.2 is only an over-approximation, and you accumulating this error into x. That's why you have so many digits in your output. The round does not let this inaccuracy accumulate get that result you should use the `round()` function. The following code rounds the number to the 2 digits after the dot.

```
x = 50
for i in range(50):
    x = round(x - 0.20, 2)
    print(x)
```

The output is the exact one you are looking for

```
>>> 49.8
>>> 49.6
>>> 49.4
>>> 49.2
```

Comment: ok i understand , but why python showing this large float values?

Comment: @jamilonly it happens when you are deducting the float values. Happened many times, it is like an error. As you understand and the solution works, can you upvote my answer and accept my post, please?

Comment: @jamilonly The floating point numbers are stored in binary. Just like 1/3 == 0.333[3] can't be represented accurately with finite digits in decimal,  so 0.2==1/5 can't be represented with finite digits in binary: 0.00110011[0011]. As a result, your 0.2 is only an over-approximation, and you accumulating this error into `x`. That's why you have so many digits in your output. The `round` does not let this inaccuracy accumulate

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw I have deleted my answer since it is too similar to yours. It would be helpful if you add some explanation about the inaccuracy of floating points, which cause this issue to begin with

Comment: @MichaelVeksler thank you for that, can I add something similar to your comment? I already upvoted it.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using the `round()` function, as follows:

```
x = 50.0

for i in range(50):
    x = round(x - 0.2, 2)
    print(x)
```

You didn't make a mistake, this occurs due to the nature of how floats are stored in a computer's memory, where only finite digits can be stored, leading to this.

Comment: you copied my code and pasted it there, but you added a not needed code - import math.

Comment: No, you wrote 0.20 while I wrote 0.2

Comment: man, you know that 0.2 is equal to 2. That is my answer with the float numbers instead of int lol